# Python 3.9: installing scikit-learn fails on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, pip, python-3.9

I'm trying to install "mlxtend"

```
pip install mlxtend
```

via command prompt but it shows a lot of errors. I've gone throw all of them but couldn't understand the reason behind the failure. Please help me to resolve this issue?

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Probably, It is a problem with scikit-learn package. Try installing by "python -m pip install SomePackage" ... and specify python version such as python3.7 or other

Comment: you should use CMD, of course

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include any necessary source code, data, and error messages as text. Consider [these reasons and guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to install `scikit-learn` which fails to install with Python 3.9 on Windows because it detects the OS as `AIX` and as such fails to build.

The details of the issue: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/18621

A way around before there is a new version of the library that successfully installs you can use (to install the release candidate):

```
pip install --pre -U scikit-learn
```